# Laravel 9.5 throwing cors error despite using the HandleCors middleware

Tags: cors, laravel-9

I have a Laravel API setup using Laravel 9.5.
The API is hosted on a VPS & I'm making an API request from a react application from localhost.
I'm using the Laravel default HandleCors middleware in Application global middleware.

```
    protected $middleware = [
         ..............
        \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class,
         ..............
    ];
```

After debugging the issue, I figured out that when making the request from the React app, Laravel is returning an error from the preFlight request. And the Network tab is showing the message: **Failed to load response data: no resource with given identifier**

But when making a request from the browser console, I'm getting a response that has property `type: cors`  & `redirected: true` but it passes the preFlight section.

Here's the config/cors.php file contents:

```
<?php

return [

    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie', 'api/v1/*', 'api/v1/panel/*', 'api/v1/hotels/*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => false,

];
```

**How Can I solve this issue?**

FYI: I can make requests successfully from POSTMAN.

Comment: Put `\Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class` first in `$middleware`.

Comment: I've already tried that, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Ok. What does your browser's Console tab say?

Comment: Only this: Navigated to http://localhost:3000/login

Comment: Your issue isn't related to CORS, then.

Comment: But I see that my requests are not getting passed the HandleCors middleware

Comment: The requests are basically getting failed from pre flight:
        if ($this->cors->isPreflightRequest($request)) {
            $response = $this->cors->handlePreflightRequest($request);

            $this->cors->varyHeader($response, 'Access-Control-Request-Method');

            return $response;
        }